# How to generate random numbers in the form _ _ _ . _ _ _ _ (C language)

Tags: c, random, numbers

Ive been trying to figure this out for the past couple of days and I just cannot do it. Im trying to generate random numbers in the form _ _ _ . _ _ _ _

so 3 digits before a decimal place and then 4 decimal places.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Dean

Comment: Are just asking about the output formatting?

Comment: Generate a random number from 0 to 9999999 and divide by 10000

Comment: And then use `printf("%8.4f\n", r);` to format the result.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Maybe better divide by 10000.0.

Comment: just want to print it out on a screen.
and the 0 to 9999999 divide by 10000 doesnt work becuase it could generate 8457 divide by 10000 and then output 0.8457 which doesnt have 3 digits infront of the decimal place

Comment: Then follow @FredLarson's advice but use `printf("%08.4f\n", r);` instead

Comment: int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int number;
   double p;
   number = rand() % 9999999;
   p = (double)number / 1;

   printf("%8.4f\n", p);

   getchar();
   return(0);


}

Answer (score 1):

There are two slight problems with the code you posted.

The first is that `rand() % 9999999` can only return values from 0 to 9999998. You probably meant to write `rand() % 10000000`.

The other problem is that `rand() % 10000000` is going to give you slightly skewed results. I'll try to explain why.

The `rand()` function returns a value from 0 to `RAND_MAX`, which in most cases has a value of `0x7fffffff`, or 2147483647. (If you're using Visual Studio, then it's only `0x7fff`, but let's hope that isn't the case.)

Since `RAND_MAX` isn't an exact multiple of 10^7, you will be slightly less likely to select random values higher than `RAND_MAX % 10000000` (i.e., 7483647). This means your results will be slightly skewed towards the range 0-7483647.

To fix this, calculate `rand()` modulus the next power of 2 higher than the top of your target range, and discard the result if it is too high. The computational overhead is negligible.

Here's some code that fixes the issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    double p;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (1) {
        number = rand() % 16777216;  /* Next power of 2 higher than 10^7 */
        if (number < 10000000) break;
    }
    p = number / 10000.0;
    printf("%08.4f\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `RAND_MAX` may _sadly_ only be [32767](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx).  Suggest `((1LU*rand()) << 15) ^ rand()` to compensate

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know of a way that I could take these random numbers, and place them into a 5 by 5 array. With each element being a different random number, not the same one?

Comment: @Dwhaley Yes, but it won't fit in this comment, and I have to go now anyway. Just try it yourself. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int number;
   double p;
   number = rand() % 9999999;
   p = (double)number / 100;


   printf("%8.4f\n", p);

   getchar();
   return(0);


}
```

Comment: `rand() % 9999999` generates, at best 999,999 different numbers. `"_ _ _ . _ _ _ _"` looks like 1,000,000 different patterns.

Comment: Why `/ 100`?  I'd expect `/ 10000.0`.